# Setting op polymorphic relation - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

I'm trying to setup a polymorphic relation between Users & Organizations, to Repositories.

Repository.php

```
public function owner(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

User.php

```
public function repositories(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Repository::class, 'owner');
}
```

Organization.php

```
public function repositories(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Repository::class, 'owner');
}
```

repository_has_owners table:

| id | repository_id | owner_id | owner_type | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | App\User |  |  |

However, when I try to query this relationship in tinker, it return this error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'repositories.owner_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `repositories` where `repositories`.`owner_id` = 1 and `repositori es`.`owner_id` is not null and `repositories`.`owner_type` = App\Models\User)'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error is clear: the repositories table does not  have a column `owner_id` ...

Comment: It indeed doesn't, as you can read in the error. However all I need from repositories is the id column. The relationship shouldn't be querying for owner_id in the repositories table.

Comment: Thats how Morph relationships work. are you sure you don't need `morphToMany` and `morphByMany`

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest for this use case. What do you recommend?

Comment: Depends.. is it a many to many relationship -> morphToMany & morphByMany

Comment: One Repository can have one owner (User or Organization).

Comment: Than why do you have an extra table? Put the owner_id and owner_type in the repositories table.

Comment: Because an owner can have multiple repositories.

Comment: Its a One to Many relationship. so you don't need the extra table. If there is a `owner_id` and `owner_type` in the repositories table, you can have multiple repositories per owner. but only one owner per repository